# Sinusoidal steering on SO(3) Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, control-theory, nonlinear-system

This is part of an exercise from Shankar's book [Nonlinear Systems: Analysis, Stability, and Control](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387985138), Problem 8.11, p.381, which is a satellite control problem.

I rephrase my question as follows. Give a bilinear control system

$$\dot{g}=g\left(u_1(t)\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}+u_2(t)\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
or in short notation
$$\dot{g}=g(u_1E_1+u_2E_2)$$
where $g\in SO(3)$, and $u_1,u_2$ are control terms. The objective is to steering the system from some given initial state $g_i$ to some final desired state $g_f$ within some finite time $T$. Now we restrict controls to be of the form
$$u_1(t)=a_0+a_1\sin2\pi t$$
$$u_2(t)=b_0+b_1\cos2\pi t$$
where $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$ are constants. The question is, how to choose the four constants?

A general solution is out of the question, since $E_1$ and $E_2$ do not commute. In fact their Lie bracket generates another matrix $E_3$ and together they form a basis for the lie algebra ${so}(3)$.

At the end of Shankar's paper [The structure of optimal controls for a steering problem](http://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/w_Sastry.pdf), controls of similar form is given, but the frequency is not prescribed.

The original exercise also points to references [257](http://home.deib.polimi.it/sarti/CV_and_publications_files/1993_CDC_left-invatiant_control_systems_matrix_lie_groups.pdf) and [320](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4793084&tag=1), but I find them useful for other parts of the original exercise.

My last thought would be to discretize the interval $[0,T]$, and treat control on each time slot to be constant. The general solution for this approximation would be a function of $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$. The rest is essentially solving an optimization problem on $\mathbb{R}^4$, but I think this is far from ideal.

Is there any analytical way to solve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you more interested in solving this particular problem as posed or knowing how to do a real design for a satellite attitude controller? While I'm sure there's some interesting math in this approach it is laughable from the point of view of an engineer trying to design an actual system.

Comment: @ALB, yes, i'm more interested in solving this particular problem as is posed mathematically here in math.SE. It might start from the satellite attitude control problem which admits many control methods, but it also has applications in other fields such as control in the quantum level. From an engineering point of view, open loop control usually is laughable when PID controller can solve most of the problem (which does not even require a specific model).